# Spring batch multithreading problem with Iterator Item Reader

Tags: java, multithreading, spring-boot, spring-batch, nosuchelementexception

I'm new to spring batch and still learning, I have batch configuration with IteratorItemReader , Custom Processor and Custom Writer as below,

```
@Autowired
JobBuilderFactory jobBuilderFactory;
@Autowired
StepBuilderFactory stepBuilderFactory;
@Value("${inputFile.location}")
private String inputFile;

@Bean
public Job testJob() throws IOException {
    return jobBuilderFactory.get("testJob")
                .incrementer(new RunIdIncrementer())
                .start(testStep())
                .listener(new JobListener())
                .build();
}

@Bean
public Step testStep() throws IOException {
    return stepBuilderFactory.get("testStep")
                .<File, File>chunk(1)
                .reader(testReader())
                .processor(testProcessor())
                .writer(testWriter())
                .taskExecutor(threadPoolTaskExecutor())
                .build();
}

@Bean
public ItemReader<File> testReader() throws IOException {
    List<File> files = Files.walk(Paths.get(inputFile), 1)
                    .filter(Files::isRegularFile)
                    .map(Path::toFile)
                    .collect(Collectors.toList());

        return new IteratorItemReader<>(files);
}

@Bean
public CustomProcessor testProcessor() {
    return new CustomProcessor();
}

@Bean
public CustomWriter testWriter() {
    return new CustomWriter();
}
@Bean
public ThreadPoolTaskExecutor threadPoolTaskExecutor() {
    ThreadPoolTaskExecutor executor = new ThreadPoolTaskExecutor();
    executor.setCorePoolSize(4);
    executor.setMaxPoolSize(6);
    executor.setQueueCapacity(4);
    executor.initialize();
    return executor;
}
```

Here testReader() will check the given input path and list all the files into a List then it returns IteratorItemReader, and then in processor business logic is happening.

with multithreading  If there are multiple files (more than one) in the input location everything is working fine, i'm not getting any error but,

Problem Statement :   Let's say there's only one file in the input location (Ex: C:/User/documents/abc.txt), one thread will process the file completely everything is ok but in the end i'm getting this below exception,

```
ERROR - Encountered an error executing step testStep in job testJob
java.util.NoSuchElementException: null
at java.util.ArrayList$Itr.next(ArrayList.java:864)
at org.springframework.batch.item.support.IteratorItemReader.read  (IteratorItemReader.java:70)
at org.springframework.batch.core.step.item.SimpleChunkProvider.doRead (SimpleChunk Provider.java:99)
at org.springframework.batch.core.step.item.SimpleChunkProvider.read (SimpleChunkProvider.java:180)
at org.springframework.batch.core.step.item.SimpleChunkProvider$1.doInIteration (SimpleChunk Provider.java:126)
at org.springframework.batch.repeat.support.RepeatTemplate.getNextResult (RepeatTemplate.java:375)
at org.springframework.batch.repeat.support.RepeatTemplate.executeInternal (RepeatTemplate.java:215)
at org.springframework.batch.repeat.support.RepeatTemplate.iterate(RepeatTemplate.java:145)
at org.springframework.batch.core.step.item.SimpleChunk Provider.provide (SimpleChunkProvider.java:118)
at org.springframework.batch.core.step.item. ChunkOrientedTasklet.execute(ChunkOrientedTasklet.java:71)
at org.springframework.batch.core.step.tasklet.TaskletStep$ChunkTransactionCallback.doInTransaction (TaskletStep.java:407)
at org.springframework.batch.core.step.tasklet.TaskletStep$ChunkTransactionCallback.doInTransaction(TaskletStep.java:331)
at org.springframework.transaction.support. Transaction Template.execute(Transaction Template.java:140)
at org.springframework.batch.core.step.tasklet.TaskletStep$2.doInChunkContext (TaskletStep.java:273)
at org.springframework.batch.core.scope.context.StepContextRepeatCallback.doInIteration (StepContextRepeatCallback.java:82)
at org.springframework.batch.repeat.support.TaskExecutorRepeatTemplate$ExecutingRunnable.run (TaskExecutorRepeatTemplate.java:262)
at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1149)
at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:624)
at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:750)
```

This Exception is happening because of multithreading only, when i tried to look into the **IteratorItemReader** class line number **70** i've found this below code,

```
if (iterator.hasNext())
    return iterator.next();
else
    return null; // end of data
```

What will be the best solution to over come this issue please provide your inputs on this,

Thanks in advance.

any suggestions would be helpful.

Comment: Multiple threads call `hasNext` all get `true` they all call `next()`.. That fails. `Iterator` isn't thread-safe so your solution is wrong. It also feels wrong to have an iterator to list files and then read them in a processor. Feels like you should be using a `MultiResourceItemReader` with a `FlatFileItemReader` instead. But that depends on what you are all doing in your processor. Else wrap the `IteratorItemReader` in a `SynchronizedItemStreamReader` to make it (sort of) thread-safe.

Comment: Hi @M.Denium thanks for your time and your inputs, i just have one doubt adding **synchronized** to reader method will do any magic here? like `public synchronized ItemReader<File> testReader(){ }`

Comment: No it won't. As stated you need to wrap it in the `SynchronizedItemStreamReader`.

Comment: i'm very new to this spring batch can you please provide sample of how to wrap it in the `SynchronizedItemStreamReader`

Answer (score 0):

Directly wrapping it in a `SynchronizedItemStreamReader` does not work, as that needs an `ItemStreamReader`, but `IteratorItemReader` is not an `ItemStreamReader`.
I figure that the best way out would be to create a custom `SynchronizedIteratorItemReader`. It would be the exact same as an `IteratorItemReader`, just that the `read()` method should be marked as synchronized.